# display number in a slot machine style custom view

Tags: android, view, android-widget, slot

I have a number that I want to display in my view like this.

[image]

Currently, I have one textView with a gradient background and some margin for each algarism of the number. 
This is not very elegant as I need to implement this in multiple activities so I would like to create a custom widget/view that i can just pass the number and it would display like I want.

Any ideas how I could implement this?
Thank you for your help

Comment: This shouldn't be to hard to make if no animations will be needed. Extend the `View` class and then draw the numbers composing the full number in the `onDraw` method.